# Wifi thermostat to replace old mechanical 2-wire 110V Honeywell?

Tags: thermostat, heating, baseboard, hydronic

I have hydronic baseboard heating in my house, which is controlled by an old mechanical Honeywell thermostat.

The Honeywell is 110V and connected with 2 wires (black/red). There is a bare ground wire as well, but no other wires that run from the boiler to the thermostat.

I would like to replace the old mechanical thermostat with a WIFI enabled heat-only thermostat without running new wires.

But I have a hard time finding any options. All smart line voltage thermostats I can find require a neutral or common wire, which I don't have.

Do you know of any WiFi thermostats that would work in my situation with 2 110v wires only (and without rewiring)?

Thanks so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: 110V is now 120V. But black/red implies 2 hots = 240V, which also matches with "the neutral problem". So which is it, 120V or 240V? Model #s of existing heater and/or thermostat would help.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! 
When measured with a volt meter, one wire showed voltage, the other one didn't. So it seems that there is just 1 hot wire.

I added a picture to the original post, which may help describe the situation I'm looking at.

Comment: Just attached a picture. Unfortunately my knowledge with wires/voltage is very limited as you can tell. I had a home inspector take a look at the system a while ago and I remember that when he used a voltage tester, it showed power on one wire, but not the other. 

On top of that, there's a bare ground wire that sits inside the box the thermostat is screwed onto.

Comment: The bare ground should be screwed into the box, but that's not the real problem. I think you actually have a switch loop, in which case you will see voltage on one wire and not on the other. Turn off power. Disconnect the black and white wires and position them so that they are away from the metal box and away from each other. Turn on the breaker. Test (carefully) voltage: between black and white, between black and ground, between white and ground. Turn off the breaker and put everything back together as before. That will give us a little more info about what we're dealing with here.

Comment: Awesome! I will do that! I'm not currently at the house but will do as soon as I get there again. 

If it is what you assume (switch loop), do you know if there are any WiFi thermostat for that with the existing wiring?

Thanks so much again!!

Comment: If it is a switch loop then lack of a neutral is likely a big problem. A thermostat (or other smart device) has to get power from somewhere. That can be "leak through hot" (works with some light bulbs, not so well with LEDs, no idea if that works with heaters), "neutral" (easiest when you have it), "hot to hot" (for 240V devices, but doesn't work if all you have is a switch loop), battery (but then you have to change it periodically), ground (very limited circumstances and only when designed that way). For typical **non** line voltage thermostats most common is a 24V transformer.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram of your boiler + the wiring at your boiler please?

Comment: That is very bizarre. It looks like someone used a 240V "line voltage thermostat" and 120/240V house wiring as a method to connect a thermostat to a hydronic system, which I would expect to use 24V controls.  That might be "a cheesy hack" to avoid fishing thermostat wires into the walls, using 24V but putting it on 120/240V wiring.  We can work with that, but would need to see where that cable goes.

Comment: wifi thermostats don't switch heavy mains loads like baseboard thermostats. You can just drive a relay to switch the big load from a wifi thermostat, but you might need a few supporting components to make it work reliably and safely.

Comment: All great feedback! Thank you!

I will take additional pictures the next time I'm at the house.

What I can share is this:

The boiler is over 30 years old - likely closer to 40. So this is a very old system. My understanding is that the thermostat is a simple switch that opens/closes an electrical circuit that powers the burner on the boiler and the circulator pump for the heating zone.

Rewiring to low voltage + relay are all options. But for the time being my goal is t find a WiFi thermostat that will work for this system out of the box (if it exists :)

Comment: @Oliver what the prior installer did is quite a bizarre kludge indeed, and won't play nicely with a modern boiler for that matter -- it's probably best to re-engineer this now instead of perpetuating the kludge